# Sales Prospecting automation using recommendation

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, mahout-recommender

This question is related to assignment of prospects to sales team using recommendation system which will increase the win rate of sales team.

I want to develop a recommendation system which will recommend the set of sales people for prospects based on performance history of sales person.

(Prospect- the contact of buyer who fit to buy company's goods.)

The design can be like there is recommendation model prepared using sales team history and for new prospects the system recommends set of sales people to attend the call.

I have huge dataset of sales history and I can gather sales team details like sales-person-id, expertise in products, success rate win/loss, client rating, location, availability and so on.

Any suggestions to develop such type of recommendation system using Spark ML or Mahout?

Answer (score 1):

just to name 2 ideas, what do you think of:

- Logistic regression: train a model that will give you probability of sale for a given example, you then order from highest to lowest to recommend the one with the biggest value.
- Collaborative filtering recomendation.

Comment: could you please share more details about the first approach. I have tried Collaborative filtering using spark but there is only limitation that it accepts 3 columns( i.e. userid, productId, rating ) to prepare the model, based on the model it provides user to products and products recommendations. My dataset has multiple dimensions. is there anyways to use more columns in approach 2?

Comment: This example goes in detailed info, the  general idea would be that you will need training data labeled with 2 classes(for example: sold,not sold). You train a logistic regression classifier ,this classifiers output will be the probability of new examples belonging to your positive class(for example "sold"). So your system can list a number of prospects, feed them to your logistic regression classifier and it will output a probability for every prospect, you then sort your prospect from higher probabilith to lowest and recommend them in that order(or  you can even define a threshold)(1/2)

Comment: a threshold  like  :
if prospect_prob> threshold:
   recommend();

The detailed example that i mentioned is:
https://developer.ibm.com/spark/blog/2016/02/22/predictive-model-for-online-advertising-using-spark-machine-learning-pipelines/

Comment: thanks for sharing details. its really helpful. how to use collaborative filtering with n number of features?

Comment: I have no used Mllib, so i dont know why it limits to 3 features or how to solve it, but for dimenctionality reduction you could use PCA(principal components analysis) and get a lowest number of correlated features.

Comment: Any news on this,hope the ideas can be useful to your project :)

Comment: Yeah definitely they are useful. I am going through business requirement and trying to design the system.